# Product page url issue

Tags: magento-1.7, url, product-urls

My magento community version is Magento ver. 1.7.0.2.

I need product detail page for http://www.indiaflowerplaza.com/eggless-cakes/eggless-lemon-cake.html

I have to enable Use Categories Path for Product URLs.

But product detail page also open in http://www.indiaflowerplaza.com/eggless-lemon-cake.html
url.

so, How to fix this issue

Comment: No, remove the use categories path and just prefix the products otherwise you will have all sorts of ranking problems - /eggless-cakes-eggless-lemon-cake.html - and get rid of the .html - no-one uses it any more.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. It's a feature.
The product can be reached at many urls.
For example let's take product with url key 'product.html' and the id 33.
Let's assume the product is in 2 categories.  category1 (id 20) and category2 (id 30).
You get the product page at the following urls:

1. /category1/product.html
2. /category2/product.html
3. /product.html
4. catalog/product/view/id/33
5. catalog/product/view/id/33/category/20
6. catalog/product/view/id/33/category/30

The backend setting you enabled does not make the product not available at the simple url (product.html in the example above). It just makes the links listed on a category page to have the category key in front of the product key.
And it would be kind of hard to have a unique url determined by a category and the product keys.
This is because of the feature that allows you to place a product in multiple categories.
For example, in the search results you cannot determine what category to use in the url if there are 2 or more categories.